# Global variable in sub-function no need to declare

Tags: php

whether to do a declare variable when a variable is in a sub-function ?

Like the example carried this:

```
function cobasaja(){
   global $coba;
   return $coba;
}

function ditampilkan(){
   global $coba;

   $coba = "content trying...";
   return cobasaja();
}

echo "View: ".ditampilkan();
```

Why it can not be like this:

```
function cobasaja(){
   global $coba;
   return $coba;
}

function ditampilkan(){
   //global $coba; <= not declare in viewer function

   $coba = "content trying...";
   return cobasaja();
}

echo "View: ".ditampilkan();
```

But the second experiment did not work.

Because as I recall, usually the second way can be done, but now I do it can not, is this because of its PHP version or setting in PHP.ini ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a function creates a new [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Any variables you want to use in the function need to be either defined in that scope, brought in from the outer scope with `global`, or passed in as parameters. This general concept has not changed much over PHP versions as far as I know, so I don't believe your second experiment would have worked in an earlier PHP version, or could work by changing a configuration setting.

If your functions are in the same class, you can use object properties rather than global variables to achieve something like what you want.

```
class Example {

    private $coba = '';

    protected function cobasaja() {
       return $this->coba;
    }

    public function ditampilkan() {
       $this->coba = "content trying...";
       return $this->cobasaja();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you are right, i might forget if i ever do this or not, btw your information is very petrified and thanks for the example given :)